# Want to diplay vwap only if current screen resolution is less than 60 mins using fuction, " timeframe.period"

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

***DISPLAY VWAP ONLY IF CURRENT TIME FRAME IS LESS THAN 60MINS***
HOW DO I SOLVE IT?

code with error

```
//@version=4
study("VWAP/MVWAP", overlay = true)
vwaplength= input(title="VWAP Length", type=input.integer, defval=1)
emaSource1= input(title="EMA 1 Source", type=input.source, defval=close)

tf1 =  (timeframe.period < 60 ? 1 : 0)    //<---- this gives the error

cvwap = ema(vwap,vwaplength)
plotvwap = plot(tf1 and cvwap ? cvwap : na,color= color.navy, transp=0, title = "VWAP", linewidth=3, display =display.all)
```

//error:
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 18: Cannot call 'operator <' with arguments (string, literal integer); available overloads: <(float, float) => bool; <(input float, input float) => input bool; <(const float, const float) => const bool; <(float, series[float]) => series[bool]; <(series[float], float) => series[bool]; <(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool];
line 25: Undeclared identifier 'tf1'

Answer (score 0):

`timeframe.period` is a string, you can't compare it with a number, you can try the following solution:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script",overlay=true)
a = time("60")
b = time(timeframe.period)
c = 0
c := a-b < 0 ? 1 : c[1]
plot(vwap/c)
```

The vwap will only be displayed if the time frame is inferior to 1 hour.

Comment: This fails when, when current time is monthly and set time is weekly. 
The indicator shows itself.

A = weekly  //set by me
b = month // current timeframe

but the indicator shows itself, 

All the rest timeframes like, daily, hourly work fine.

What is the issue? Logic is fine

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
reshigher=input.timeframe("240", title="Higher TF MAs Resolution")
// Show if Current timeframe is only lower (timeframe.period) than timeframe selected (reshigher)
check_res = bool( timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period) < timeframe.in_seconds(reshigher) )

...

smahg1plothigher = plot( check_res ? (switch_2 ? MA1_MTF : na ) : na , color=#2ecc71, linewidth=1, title='(2) Higher SMA 1' )
```

Comment: use the built-in ```timeframe.in_seconds()```  to compare timeframes